# How to calculate the product of the elements in a Javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I was looking for a good explanation of calculating product of the elements in one array, but the answers I found are not working in my case.
I'm trying to find the product of two arrays and compare them.
Found some articles where is written that I can use this function:

```
    let total = 1; 
    for(let i = 0; i <= array.lenght; i++){
        if(isNaN(array[i])){
            continue;
        }else{
            total *= Number(array[i]);
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

No matter what are the values in the array I'm always getting 1 as total. I'm posting the code, so if someone can show me my mistake or tell me some other way to calculate the product, I'll be very grateful.

[Here's the code link](https://pastebin.com/67rRWwVH)

Comment: except for the spelling error of "lenght" your code seems to do the job. I run the code with a bunch of different number arrays... The output seems fine to me

Comment: Debug tips: Try to use some debugger and you can check step by step how the variable change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your ... i <= array.lenght; i++ ... 
your length misspelled into lenght

Please correct that